Expansion and Simplification of a Hurwitz Zeta Function
On one math page I saw this simplification being made involving the Hurwitz Zeta Function easily simplifying into a normal Zeta Function form: $$\zeta(s,\frac{1}{2})=2^{s}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^{s}}=2^{s}(\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^{s}})=(2^{s}-1)\zeta(s)$$ After the first step, I am quite confused on how they have simplified it. Essentially this part:$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^{s}}=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^{s}}$$

If $\Re(s)>1$, using the absolute convergence, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^s}&=1+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\cdots\\
&=1+\bigg(\frac{1}{2^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\bigg)+\frac{1}{3^s}+\bigg(\frac{1}{4^s}-\frac{1}{4^s}\bigg)+\frac{1}{5^s}+\cdots\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^s}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k)^s}\\
&=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k)^s}.
\end{align}
